# Django+WSGI: Use app at subpath without changes

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'd like to serve a Django application from a subdirectory (for example `http://www.stackoverflow.com/django_app/`).

I've set up mod_wsgi to serve the page via

```
WSGIScriptAlias /django_app PATH_TO_DJANGO/wsgi.py
```

How can I specify settings like LOGIN_URL, STATIC_URL, MEDIA_URL, etc. so Django respects the relative path?

If set STATIC_URL it to `"/static/"` it tries to reference resources at `http://www.stackoverflow.com/static/` instead of `http://www.stackoverflow.com/django_app/static/`.

But if I set it to `"static"` (without a leading slash) it is interpreted relative to any URL which is also wrong. For example, the admin page at

`http://www.stackoverflow.com/django_app/admin/`

tries to load the files from

`http://www.stackoverflow.com/django_app/admin/static/`

I haven't found a way to tell Django to use `http://www.stackoverflow.com/django_app/static` without explicitly hardcoding the prefix `/django_app` within the settings (which IMHO violates the DRY principle because it is already specified in the mod_wsgi-config).
 It also prohibits serving the same project under different URLs without modifying the project, which seems odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for it to be automatic. The URLs in those few variables, and LOGOUT_URL, are not automatically prefixed with the SCRIPT_NAME which is passed in with scripts and which identifies the mount point.

Comment: Seems like a design flaw in Django.

Comment: It turns out that Django 1.4 added something to help with this. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy